# How to set __doc__ correctly for the autocompletion of C++ libraries

Tags: python-jedi

We have a pybind11 module and want code completion with Jedi for its classes and functions. Our approach was to set the docstring `__doc__` of the functions so that Jedi can use them for its completion. When we call `completions()` we get an empty list. Jedi prints no errors, also not via the set_debug_function.

We set the path to the module in the string passed to Jedi. Also the import of the module is included in this string.

What do we have to do to make Jedi auto complete custom C++ library classes and functions? Does this generally work using `__doc__` and if so, what should the format look like?

**UPDATE:** Thanks to Dave's comment we were able to further analyze the problem. Here follows an example:

```
import bitbuffer
bb = bitbuffer.BitBuffer(100)
bitbuffer. # completion works for the module
bitBuffer.BitBuffer. # completion works for the class
bb. # completion does not work for the instance of the class
```

Here follows the `set_debug_function()` output of Jedi 0.14.0 for the completion of `bb.`:

```
speed: init 17.217941999435425
speed: parsed 17.218032836914062
dbg: Start: completions

  dbg: eval_node <Name: bb@5,0>@(5, 0) in <ModuleContext: @1-5 is_stub=False>
  dbg: finder.filter_name 'bb' in (<ModuleContext: @1-5 is_stub=False>): [<TreeNameDefinition: string_name=bb start_pos=(3, 0)>]@(5, 0)
   dbg: eval_expr_stmt <ExprStmt: bb = bitbuffer.BitBuffer(100)@3,0> (<Name: bb@3,0>)
    dbg: eval_node PythonNode(atom_expr, [<Name: bitbuffer@3,5>, PythonNode(trailer, [<Operator: .>, <Name: BitBuffer@3,15>]), PythonNode(trailer, [<Operator: (>, <Number: 100>, <Operator: )>])])@(3, 5) in <ModuleContext: @1-5 is_stub=False>
     dbg: eval_node <Name: bitbuffer@3,5>@(3, 5) in <ModuleContext: @1-5 is_stub=False>
     dbg: finder.filter_name 'bitbuffer' in (<ModuleContext: @1-5 is_stub=False>): [<TreeNameDefinition: string_name=bitbuffer start_pos=(1, 7)>]@(3, 0)
     speed: import (<Name: bitbuffer@1,7>,) <ModuleContext: @1-5 is_stub=False> 0.0019109249114990234

     dbg: global search_module 'bitbuffer': <CompiledObject: <module 'bitbuffer' from '/home/software/build-Debug/install/myApp/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bitbuffer.so'>>
     dbg: after import: S{<CompiledObject: <module 'bitbuffer' from '/home/software/build-Debug/install/myApp/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bitbuffer.so'>>}
     dbg: finder._names_to_types: [<TreeNameDefinition: string_name=bitbuffer start_pos=(1, 7)>] -> S{<CompiledObject: <module 'bitbuffer' from '/home/software/build-Debug/install/myApp/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bitbuffer.so'>>}
    dbg: eval_trailer: PythonNode(trailer, [<Operator: .>, <Name: BitBuffer@3,15>]) in S{<CompiledObject: <module 'bitbuffer' from '/home/software/build-Debug/install/myApp/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bitbuffer.so'>>}
    dbg: finder.filter_name 'BitBuffer' in (<CompiledObject: <module 'bitbuffer' from '/home/software/build-Debug/install/myApp/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bitbuffer.so'>>): [<CompiledName: (<CompiledContextName: string_name=bitbuffer>).BitBuffer>]@None
    dbg: finder._names_to_types: [<CompiledName: (<CompiledContextName: string_name=bitbuffer>).BitBuffer>] -> S{<CompiledObject: <pybind11_builtins.pybind11_type object at 0x55be2f8f7278>>}
    dbg: eval_trailer: PythonNode(trailer, [<Operator: (>, <Number: 100>, <Operator: )>]) in S{<CompiledObject: <pybind11_builtins.pybind11_type object at 0x55be2f8f7278>>}
    dbg: global search_module 'builtins': <CompiledObject: <module 'builtins' (built-in)>>

    dbg: execute: <CompiledObject: <pybind11_builtins.pybind11_type object at 0x55be2f8f7278>> <TreeArguments: <Number: 100>>
    dbg: execute result: S{<CompiledInstance of <CompiledObject: <pybind11_builtins.pybind11_type object at 0x55be2f8f7278>>(<TreeArguments: <Number: 100>>)>} in <CompiledObject: <pybind11_builtins.pybind11_type object at 0x55be2f8f7278>>
   dbg: eval_expr_stmt result S{<CompiledInstance of <CompiledObject: <pybind11_builtins.pybind11_type object at 0x55be2f8f7278>>(<TreeArguments: <Number: 100>>)>}
  dbg: finder._names_to_types: [<TreeNameDefinition: string_name=bb start_pos=(3, 0)>] -> S{<CompiledInstance of <CompiledObject: <pybind11_builtins.pybind11_type object at 0x55be2f8f7278>>(<TreeArguments: <Number: 100>>)>}
 dbg: trailer completion contexts: S{<CompiledInstance of <CompiledObject: <pybind11_builtins.pybind11_type object at 0x55be2f8f7278>>(<TreeArguments: <Number: 100>>)>}

 dbg: Start: convert contexts
 dbg: End: convert contexts
dbg: End: completions
```

Why does Jedi not return a completion for the object instance `bb`? `dir(bb)` in the shell works and generates the following output:

```
['__bool__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'capacity', 'clear', 'copy', 'data', 'desc', 'fill', 'from_int', 'marks', 'name', 'offset', 'pack', 'shadow', 'size', 'unpack']
```

**UPDATE #2 HINT:**
The Jedi interpreter is able to complete our object:

```
script = jedi.Interpreter("bb.", [locals()])
script.completions() # this works
```

We conclude that there is no problem with the object itself.

**UPDATE #3:**

Auto completion of the object works with jedi 0.11.1, but not with 0.14.0. We assume that something is broken in later versions.

Comment: Jedi is not using `__doc__` for completions. It's simply there to show the help text. So that might be valuable, but for something else. Jedi uses `dir(module)`, which means that if that works in the shell, it should work everywhere. It would also be interesting to have the output when `set_debug_function()` was called.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. We have added new information and would appreciate further assistance.

Comment: @DaveHalter Should we open an issue in Jedi's issue tracker for this?

Comment: Yeah, please do. It makes no sense to use the comment functions here. However, I feel like there might also be an issue with the class itself. Jedi has improved quite a bit since 0.11 and it might just work there, because something was even more wrong in 0.11.

Comment: If someone is interested to this topic, here you'll find the follow up: https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/1388